# How to compare two list and print the difference number

Tags: python, list

I have two unordered list

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to compare two list and print the new item added to list b

after comparing two list

I need to get the value 1 from the above list

I tried compare and sort libraries, but didn't found the right solution, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Perhaps look into https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice use of `Counter` here, subtract the occurence of `x` to the ones of `b` and keep the keys only

```
from collections import Counter

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

c = Counter(b) - Counter(x)
keep = list(c) # keys only
print(keep)  # [1]
```

Comment: `Counter(b) - Counter(x)` ?

Comment: @OlvinRoght damn nice